# Reading string by string in a line - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an input text file "input.txt" that looks like this:

```
Country Code ID QTY
FR  B000X2D 75 130
FR  B000X2E 75 150
```

How do I extract the first, second and the third string from each line?

This code maps a whole line into one field of array:

```
f = File.open("input.txt", "r")
line_array = []
f.each_line { |line| line_array << line }
f.close
puts line_array[1]
```

Which outputs:

```
FR  B000X2D 75 130
```

Furthermore, how can I split one line into more lines based on a quantity number,

```
max(quantity) = 50 per line
```

so that the output is:

```
FR  B000X2D 75 50
FR  B000X2D 75 50
FR  B000X2D 75 30
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is space delimited, should be pretty easy to split things up:

```
File.readlines('input.txt').map do |line|
  country, code, id, qty = line.chomp.split(/\s+/)

  [ country, code, id.to_i, qty.to_i ]
end
```

You can also easily reject any rows you don't want, or select those you do, plus this helps with stripping off headers:

```
File.readlines('input.txt').reject do |line|
  line.match(/\ACountry/i)
end.map do |line|
  country, code, id, qty = line.chomp.split(/\s+/)

  [ country, code, id.to_i, qty.to_i ]
end.select do |country, code, id, qty|
  qty <= 50
end
```

Comment: could you please explain the second code, not sure if i understand the syntax for 'select'. Will I get the output I am looking for, i.e. to divide qty of 150 into 50, 50 and 30 (see my original post). How to print out the output after select? 'puts country' gives me an error for example

Comment: If you want to expand one row into multiple rows, you'll need to use `flat_map`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSV class if these are tab separated entries. CSV stands for "comma separated values" but the you can provide your own separator

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach("fname", :row_sep => "\t") do |row|
  # use row here...
end
```

See https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: As a FYI, the tab-equivalent to a CSV file is called TSV. And, as stated, Ruby's CSV can also do TSV files.